# Spark Standalone mode with master service discovery

Tags: apache-spark, consul

We have a spark standalone that has 2 masters. We are using consul to discover all of our services. So that instead of writing in worker configuration such as:
`spark://172.40.101.1:7077,172.40.102.2:7077`

we just write

```
spark://spark-master.service:7077
```

The problem is that if for example 172.40.101.1 is standby and 172.40.102.2 is active, and in the first time the worker will get 101.1 then it will not try again. Seems like it is static.

Now I can work around using dig and linux parsing, But my questions are:

1. Is the worker config static ?
2. Is there a best practice for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem.  The first is how do you identify an active (or standby) spark?  The second is how can you use that information to connect to the proper one?

If you can tell, either by a web url get or a process manipulation which one is active, and which one(s) are standby, you can create a service / health check based on that.  Googling around a bit, I see the spark consul service and it's health check here:

```
{
"service": {
  "name": "spark-master",
  "port": 7077,
  "checks": [
    {
      "script": "ps aux | grep -v grep | grep org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master",
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

This health check finds a java process via a script.  If the process is found, then the health check succeeds. This particular health check doesn't care if it is active or standby, either matches. You would need a health check, under a service with a different name, that determines if the spark node is active.  I don't know anything about spark, but looking on the net I found this spark-submit command.  If this command works as I imagine, this might do the trick:

```
{
    "service": {
      "name":"spark-active"
      ,"port":7077
      ,"checks":[{"script": "curl --silent  http://127.0.0.1:8080/ | grep '<li><strong>Status:</strong> ALIVE</li>'| wc -l | awk '{exit (\$0 - 1) }'"
    }
}
```

Then you would connect using:

```
spark://spark-active.service:7077
```

Your health check can also connect via http. Consul service checks are documented here: https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html

-g